# Difficulty defining a working AWS role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to construct an AWS Lambda function that downloads and writes some data into an S3 bucket. The problem I am running into is that the write operation into S3 itself raises a `PermissionDenied` error.

This in turn implies that I am not writing the role correctly. However, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I have five buckets, all some variation on `mta-gtfs-N`. I've assigned the following Role to the Lambda function:

```
{   "Version": "2012-10-17",   "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents",
        "s3:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [ 
"arn:aws:s3:::mta-gtfs-1", 
"arn:aws:s3:::mta-gtfs-21", 
"arn:aws:s3:::mta-gtfs-11", 
"arn:aws:s3:::mta-gtfs-16", 
"arn:aws:s3:::mta-gtfs-2" 
]
    }   
] }
```

Can anyone spot my error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `/*` at the end of your resource string to give access to operations inside the bucket. Example: `arn:aws:s3:::mta-gtfs-1/*`

So your `Resource` array should be

```
"Resource": [ 
  "arn:aws:s3:::mta-gtfs-1/*", 
  "arn:aws:s3:::mta-gtfs-21/*", 
  "arn:aws:s3:::mta-gtfs-11/*", 
  "arn:aws:s3:::mta-gtfs-16/*", 
  "arn:aws:s3:::mta-gtfs-2/*" 
]
```

Your policy with the above Resource section would allow operations like `Get`, `Put` Object. If you want to do bucket level operation like `S3:ListBucket`, you need to omit the `/*` and use the resource names the way you are currently using but for operations like `S3:*Object` you need the `/*`(it can also be a "folder" prefix like `<Bucket>/home/*`)

Here is a [sample policy](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/) for `test` bucket. Note the usage of `/*`

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::test"]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
      ],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::test/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Accepting this answer because while Khalid's answer works, this one explains *why* it works.

Answer (score 1):

Your policy should be re-written as:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::mta-gtfs-*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
        "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
        "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::mta-gtfs-*/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```